# pass map from file to class c++

Tags: c++, unordered-map

I have this situation where I'm trying to pass a map after I populated it, from a file to a class:

**A.h** - a normal header file where I have a function prototype and a map

```
#include <unordered_map>
func1();
static std::unordered_map<glm::ivec3, Chunk*, KeyHasher> chunks;
```

**A.cpp**

```
#include "A.h"
func1() {
    // ...
    chunks.insert(pair<glm::ivec3, Chunk*>(pos, chunk));
    cout << chunks.size(); // here I have the right size
    // ...
}
```

**B.h**

```
#include "A.h"
class B {
    public:
        my_func();
}
```

**B.cpp**

```
B::my_func() {
    // ...
    cout << chunks.size(); // size is 0
    for (auto& c : chunks) {
        // ... do something
    }
}
```

My question is, why in B.cpp `chunks` map arrives empty? I thought that if I use `static` this will solve my problem. Thank you for your time!

Comment: Just FYI /- `chunks.insert(pair<glm::ivec3, Chunk*>(pos, chunk));` can be simplified to `chunks[pos] = chunk;`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are declaring the `chunks` variable as `static` in `A.h`.  That is the problem.

Every `.cpp` that `#include`'s `A.h` will get *its own copy* of the `chunks` variable.  That is why `chunks` is populated in `A.cpp` but is empty in `B.cpp`.

If you want to share the `chunks` variable across translation units, it needs to be *declared* as `extern` instead of `static`, and then *defined* in one of `.cpp` files, eg:

A.h

```
#include <unordered_map>
func1();
extern std::unordered_map<glm::ivec3, Chunk*, KeyHasher> chunks;
```

A.cpp

```
#include "A.h"

std::unordered_map<glm::ivec3, Chunk*, KeyHasher> chunks;

func1() {
    // ...
    chunks.insert(pair<glm::ivec3, Chunk*>(pos, chunk));
    cout << chunks.size(); // here I have the right size
    // ...
}
```

B.h

```
class B {
    public:
        my_func();
};
```

B.cpp

```
#include "B.h"
#include "A.h"

B::my_func() {
    // ...
    cout << chunks.size(); // here I have the right size
    for (auto& c : chunks) {
        // ... do something
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it worked! I actually tried declaring it with extern in `A.h` but I didn't define it in `A.cpp` and I was getting weird errors..

Comment: Or better yet, pass `chunks` around rather than having functions depend on a magic global state, so you'd have `using ChunksMap = std::unordered_map<glm::ivec3, Chunk*, KeyHasher>;` then `B::my_func(const ChunksMap& chunks) { ...`.